# Making a number sorting system in python 3 but getting a error ("ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' ")

Tags: python

One of the things of which I keep on banging in to when this program which open a file with numbers in it and prints them in order. The file `NewFile.txt` contains

```
1
2
3
8
3
6
1
8
3
9
10
```

What it should do is go thought every line set it as a variable then put it in order but i keep getting the error

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

At this moment in time the enter score bit is useless.

Here is the code so far:

```
Test = (input("Enter Score: "))
ffs = open("NewFile.txt", "r+")
p = 0
for i in range(1, 10):# numbers going to fine
    for u in range (1, 10):#lines Going to read
       p = (p+1)
       a = int(ffs.readline())
       if a == i:
           print (a)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`file.readline()` returns an empty string when you completed reading. An empty string cannot be turned into an integer.

You reached the end of the file because you are trying to read something *81 times*; the outer loop runs 9 times and the inner loop runs 9 times, giving you 9 * 9 == 81 iterations. You don't have that many lines in your file.

You could probably just read the file into a list:

```
with open("NewFile.txt", "r+") as ffs:
    numbers = [int(line) for line in ffs]
```

or loop through all lines in your input file *once* and handling numbers as you read them:

```
with open("NewFile.txt", "r+") as ffs:
    for line in ffs:
        number = int(line)
```

You can still encounter a line that is *empty* here; you could test for that with `if line.strip():`.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux: the OP used it; I left it in assuming they wanted to write back to the same file at some point.

Comment: Yer the point of the r+ is because i am going to make a quiz save to it then print it out in order.

Comment: @JackShake: you can always re-open the file later though.

Comment: ok i look up that. This is my second program i have ever made. Thanks for your help. also sorry for any mis spelling.